# Create env variables in a loop in bash not working

Tags: bash

I have a set of properties, and I want to create env variables in bash. The format of the properties is like this:

```
CONFIG=$(curl -s "endpoint")
echo $CONFIG
property1: value1 property2: value2 property3: value3...
```

Then I apply a replace to get '='

```
CONFIG2=${CONFIG//: /=}
echo $CONFIG2
property1=value1 property2=value2 property3=value3...
```

And finally, applying a for loop I want to add those properties

```
for property in $CONFIG2; do env "$property"; done
```

I need to use env since my properties contains . characters, export doesn't work for me. For example: property.1.thisisanexample=value1

While executing the 'for', I can see that in each iteration it is adding the current property, but after it finish and I run env, they aren't there. Any idea of what is happening and how can this be done?

Comment: You don't create any environment variable in your code.  I suggest that you run your program with `set -x` and see what's going on. Aside from this, `env "$property"` would run the program named by the variable `property`. Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: Just use an associative array to store the properties. That will (1) work and (2) accept keys containing `.` without issues.

Answer (score 0):

### #1

Assuming your CONFIG variable has or gets the following string value:

```
CONFIG='property.1.thisisanexample: value1 property.2.thisisanexample: value2 property.3.thisisanexample: value:3'
```

Then you may create a CONFIG2 parameter like in below:

*Note: This will substitute the **colon+ space** `:`  characters with a `=`*

`CONFIG2=$(echo ${CONFIG//:\ /=} )`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

CONFIG='property.1.thisisanexample: value1 property.2.thisisanexample: value2 property.3.thisisanexample: value:3'
CONFIG2=$(echo ${CONFIG//:\ /=} )

echo "${CONFIG2}"
```

Output:

```
property.1.thisisanexample=value1 property.2.thisisanexample=value2 property.3.thisisanexample=value:3
```

### #2

Now if you want to use `env` with the properties you may do the following:

```bash
for property in ${CONFIG2} ; do 
  env ${property}
done
```